# Postgresql is ignoring _ character when fetching tablenames from a database

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a lot of tables in my postgresql database, some starts with p and some starts with p_.
e.g:

```
 1. ptasi
 2. pnomu
 3. pteni
 4. p_1150
 5. p_1010
 6. p_6050
```

and when i am searching for tables starting with p_ as:

```
SELECT table_name 
FROM information_schema.tables 
WHERE table_type = 'BASE TABLE' 
AND table_name Like 'p_%'
AND table_schema = 'public'
```

it is returning all six tables

```
 1. ptasi
 2. pnomu
 3. pteni
 4. p_1150
 5. p_1010
 6. p_6050
```

instead of

```
 4. p_1150
 5. p_1010
 6. p_6050
```

How can we acheive this?

Comment: PostgreSQL doesn't *ignore* the `_`, `_` is the [single character wildcard for `LIKE` queries](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/static/functions-matching.html). Use `'p\_%'`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The underscore is a wildcard for an arbitrary character in `LIKE` expressions.

Escape it with a backslash if you want to match a literal underscore:

```
t=# with v(t) as (values('p_11'),('pop'))
select t from v where t like 'p\_%';
  t
------
 p_11
(1 row)
```

and in case you have backspace in table name (which would be very strange, but still), you can specify escape character, eg:

```
t=# with v(t) as (values('p_11'),('pop'))
select t from v where t like 'p@_%' escape '@';
  t
------
 p_11
(1 row)
```

manual: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-matching.html

> An underscore (_) in pattern stands for (matches) any single
>   character; a percent sign (%) matches any sequence of zero or more
>   characters.

Comment: I am able to fix by replacing like 'p_%' with 'p\\_%'. Thanks Vao